# How to access SVG element attribute in JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, javascript, raphael, javascript-framework

I am using Raphael to draw SVG elements.

For example, if I have SVG element

```
<image x="710" y="425" width="10" height="10" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="images/car.png" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
```

How can I access each attribute in JavaScript (further more, the access method should also be functional in IE)

Comment: Which attributes are you looking to get?  The ones right on the `image` or on the inner SVG/VML nodes?

Answer (score 1):

give the image an id element, e.g.

```
<image id="myImage" x="710" y="425" width="10" height="10" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="images/car.png" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
```

and after access it via jQuery using

```
$('#myImage').attr("width"); // getter
$('#myImage').attr("width", "400"); // setter
```

greetings

Comment: This will work in Firefox, Chrome, Safari (and IE9) etc. however in older IE versions where graphics are generated via legacy VML as a substitution for lack of SVG support - I'd expect this to fail.  Raphael.js does support a "setter" for attributes called `.attr(key, val)` or `.attr(paramMap)` http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html but I don't see a "getter" - likely due to complexities in attempting to return a uniform result across browsers.